# Why don't I get access to the React application inside Docker?

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile

I executed `npm run build` and created a react build then I build a Docker image with the Docker file.

```
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine
COPY build ./
RUN ["npm", "install", "-g", "serve"]
CMD ["serve", "-s", "build"]
```

I run this docker image with the command:

```
docker run -ip 5000:5000 steinko/testreacttutorial:1
```

Then I got the message:

> INFO: Accepting connections at http://localhost:5000

When I enter localhost:5000 in the browser I get the following:

> 404 Request path could not be found

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

please check the  `docker inspect` command output for your image to find the application port exposed and then map that to 5000 port in the `docker run` command